# Arduino + ESP8266 - how to read button press on Arduino and send it via ESP8266?

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266

I thought I solved that problem but while being at 80% of my project I discovered that its core has a terrible malfunction. I hope you guys are going to help me.

I have an Arduino with buttons. Pressing those buttons sends 1 for the first button, 2 for the second button, 4 for the third and so on - powers of number 2.

If I press the first and second button, it gives me the value 3. If there is no button pressed I get 0. Arduino has 8 buttons, so pressing all buttons together returns 511. The number is being sent only on button change. So it doesn't send a number continuously, but only on change. All that works perfectly fine.

I also have an ESP8266 module connected to the Arduino's TX and RX pins (pin 0 and 1). I can send data via `Serial1.print` to the ESP module. The ESP module sends data that comes from the Arduino to the local network and it is received by a Windows application on a specified port. All that works.

So if I press button 3 it goes like this:

- button press -> analyze which button is pressed
- -> send digit 4 to ESP
- -> ESP gets data from Arduino
- -> ESP sends digit 4 to the port on the web server

The problem comes when I start to press buttons like crazy as fast as I can (I expect such behaviour from users). I expect from my web server to get:

> 4 0 4 0 4 0 4 0 4 0

And so on because I press and release a button.

Unfortunately I sometimes get something like this:

> 4 0 4 0 4 0 4 4 0 4

It happens 2-3 times on 100 presses. As you can see, one of the button releases was lost. I tried many ways and I am almost sure that the ESP didn't send that missing 0, but surely it has been sent to the ESP. Probably it didn't get it from the Arduino and the problem lays within the `readStringUntil` function.

Here is the Arduino code:

```
String serialResponse = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(256000);
  Serial.setTimeout(5);
  Serial1.setTimeout(5);
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) button[i] = i + startPin;
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) buttonStatus[i] = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) pinMode(button[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    serialResponse = Serial.readStringUntil('\r\n');
    Serial1.println(serialResponse);
    Serial.println(serialResponse);
  }
  int currentButtonValue = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {
    currentButtonValue = currentButtonValue + int(buttonStatus[i] * (0.5 + pow(2, i)));
  }
  if (currentButtonValue != previousButtonStatus ) {
    previousButtonStatus = currentButtonValue;
    Serial1.println(currentButtonValue);
    Serial.println(currentButtonValue);
  }
}
```

And here is my ESP code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "xxx";
const char* pass = "xxx";
const char* host = "192.168.0.10";
int port = 7777;        
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(256000);
  Serial.setTimeout(5);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  if (client.connect(host, port)) {
    Serial.println("Connected to server.");
    client.print("WIFI Module connected:" + WiFi.localIP());
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (client.available()) {
    String WiFiResponse = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(WiFiResponse);
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    String SerialResponse = Serial.readStringUntil('\r\n');
    client.print(SerialResponse);
  }
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Disconnecting from server.");
    client.stop();
    while(true);
  }
```

What I checked that didn't help:

- monitored in the same time Serial in Arduino and console in Windows app. Arduino sends the correct return values on button presses, the app sometimes misses something.
- changing baud in both codes: 9600, 57600, 115200, 256000
- changing `settimeout` value up to 500 hoping the longer time it will wait it will grab that missing 0.
- tried different end of line delimiters for readStringUntil - \r \n and \r\n

I decided to use `readStringUntil` because there is a different amount of bytes being sent to the ESP. I sometimes also get different signs from ESP instead of digits for example "¦Hø".

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which esp module do you use that you program it separately?

Comment: i solved a problem - it was losing data because of logical level converter so it was a hardware issue.

Comment: Well nice. But could you be as kind as to answer my questions?